# Need to display the columns based on input values in cognos report

Tags: cognos

I have requirement. I need to create a text box prompt in the prompt page. In that prompt user may enter branch number or warehouse number. based on these input value i need to display the branch number and warehouse number in the list report. 
Ex: if user enter branch number i need to display only branch number in the list. If user enter warehouse number i need to display warehouse number in the list.

Comment: Based on a single textbox?  How would the report know whether it's a branch number or warehouse number?

Comment: Do the key ranges of warehouses and branches overlap?

Answer (score 1):

1. Two optional prompts, each tied to respective data item in query
2. Macro prompt in each data item of query, putting a dummy value in if the respective parameter is empty
3. Create list in report with both columns and measure
4. Two variables, one for each parameter, each tied to conditional rendering on the list column

[I wrote up a similar technique on my blog](http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2010/05/cognos-84-custom-report-building.html). This would automatically sum the report based on whatever data item had values entered on its prompt. It uses all built-in Cognos functionality. You would need to adapt slightly to ensure the user entered at least one value - could quickly hack with JS.

Answer (score 1):

If the branch numbers and warehouse numbers don't overlap then you can do the following:

1. Add both the branch number and warehouse number columns to your query
2. Create a new data item and put the following as the expression:

   CASE
    
   WHEN ?whse_branch_no? BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN [Branch Number]
   ELSE [Warehouse Number]
   END
3. Add the new data item to your report
4. If you are filtering on the input as well you could use similar logic:

   IF (?whse_branch_no? BETWEEN 0 AND 10)
   THEN ([Branch Number] = ?whse_branch_no?)
   ELSE ([Warehouse Number] = ?whse_branch_no?)

Obviously, you'd use your own parameter, data item names, and numerical range but the concept is the same.

If the numbers do overlap then it's more difficult.

You could add a two-option radio button that allows the user to select the context for the text box input, with Branch Number and Warehouse Number as choices. Then you just adapt the logic presented above to use the value passed in by the radio button to choose the data item you want.